# How to disable a button dynamically

Tags: wpf

I want to gray out a button dynamically. How to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in xaml

```
<Button Name="myButton">Click Me</Button>
```

in code behind

```
myButton.IsEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set its [`IsEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled.aspx) property to `false`. You can do this either in code-behind or with triggers/styles, depending on your needs there.

Answer (score 0):

here id more sophisticated way (WPF way) is to bind Command to the Button.

```
 <Button Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
```

in ViewModel which is bound to the view's dataContext:

```
public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
           return  new DelegateCommand<string>(ExecuteSomething,IsExecutable);
        }
    }
```

here is **ExecuteSomething** the method which will be executed by clicking your button
**IsExecutable** - perdicate while it returns false the Button will be disable