# Disable all controls in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Super simple question, super easy to do before WPF, and now I can't find a way to do it simply.

I am looking for something like :

```
foreach(var control in this.FrameworkElements)
{
    control.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497056/how-to-disable-a-button-dynamically

Comment: Are you sure that you need this? When you disable a parent control, typically all child controls are disabled by propagation. So it should be enough to explicitely disable the root control.

Comment: It's basically like @grek40 explained. As a little sidenote: If you are using this to disable anything and show a new "dialog"-like view you could instead consider creating a new window and calling it via myNewWindow.ShowDialog(). This should lock the original window until the new one is closed. Saves you the hassle of manually setting the correct interface elements to enabled / disabled.

Comment: Thanks you for the help, it's actually what i did. The issue was to find the correct control to disable (as allmost every controls is dynamically generated and not properly accessible). Now i can bind to my ViewModel property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There should be no need to disable all controls one by one, as `IsEnabled` is inherited - so for the following XAML:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid x:Name="GridMain">
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

you can disable all controls inside the `GridMain` by

```
GridMain.IsEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that your controls are inside a container like `Grid`,`Stackpanel`,..... You can use [`Children`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
foreach(var control in yourContainer.Children.OfType<Control>())
{
    control.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Just don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` to your `using` directives.

Comment: Thank you, just in case i couldn't find a clean way to do it, that's exactly the kind of last resort i was looking for, to be implemented in code behind